# Copying arrays from one reference to another in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, copy

I have a reference to an anonymous array and I want to create a reference to a copy of that array. Here's how I do it:

```
my $ref1 = ['a','b','c',];
my @arr = @$ref1;
my $ref2 = \@arr;
```

now $ref2 points to a copy of the array. However, I don't actually care about @arr. Is there a way to perform such a copy without an intermediate variable?

Thanks.

Comment: You could do this: `my $ref2 = [@$ref1]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create a reference to an array which is a copy of an array referenced by a variable `$ref1`, you can write:

```
my $ref2 = [@$ref1];
```

Now, `$ref2` is the new reference.

Comment: And for a deep copy, use Storage's `dclone`.